# Split pandas dataframe index

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a pretty big dataframe with column names categories (foreign trade statistics), while the index is a string containing the country code AND the year: w2013 meaning *World*, year 2013, r2015 meaning *Russian Federation*, year 2015.

```
Index([u'w2011', u'c2011', u'g2011', u'i2011', u'r2011', u'w2012', u'c2012',
   u'g2012', u'i2012', u'r2012', u'w2013', u'c2013', u'g2013', u'i2013',
   u'r2013', u'w2014', u'c2014', u'g2014', u'i2014', u'r2014', u'w2015',
   u'c2015', u'g2015', u'i2015', u'r2015'],
  dtype='object')
```

What would be the easiest way to make a multiple index for plotting the various columns - I need a column plotted for each country and each year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try create `Multiindex` `from_tuples` - for extract letters use [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str).

```
import pandas as pd

li =[u'w2011', u'c2011', u'g2011', u'i2011', u'r2011', u'w2012', u'c2012',
   u'g2012', u'i2012', u'r2012', u'w2013', u'c2013', u'g2013', u'i2013',
   u'r2013', u'w2014', u'c2014', u'g2014', u'i2014', u'r2014', u'w2015',
   u'c2015', u'g2015', u'i2015', u'r2015']

df = pd.DataFrame(range(25), index = li, columns=['a'])
print df
        a
w2011   0
c2011   1
g2011   2
i2011   3
r2011   4
w2012   5
c2012   6
g2012   7
i2012   8
r2012   9
w2013  10
c2013  11
g2013  12
i2013  13
r2013  14
w2014  15
c2014  16
g2014  17
i2014  18
r2014  19
w2015  20
c2015  21
g2015  22
i2015  23
r2015  24
```

```
print df.index.str[0]
Index([u'w', u'c', u'g', u'i', u'r', u'w', u'c', u'g', u'i', u'r', u'w', u'c',
       u'g', u'i', u'r', u'w', u'c', u'g', u'i', u'r', u'w', u'c', u'g', u'i',
       u'r'],
      dtype='object')

print df.index.str[1:]
Index([u'2011', u'2011', u'2011', u'2011', u'2011', u'2012', u'2012', u'2012',
       u'2012', u'2012', u'2013', u'2013', u'2013', u'2013', u'2013', u'2014',
       u'2014', u'2014', u'2014', u'2014', u'2015', u'2015', u'2015', u'2015',
       u'2015'],
      dtype='object')

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(df.index.str[0], df.index.str[1:]))
```

```
print df
         a
w 2011   0
c 2011   1
g 2011   2
i 2011   3
r 2011   4
w 2012   5
c 2012   6
g 2012   7
i 2012   8
r 2012   9
w 2013  10
c 2013  11
g 2013  12
i 2013  13
r 2013  14
w 2014  15
c 2014  16
g 2014  17
i 2014  18
r 2014  19
w 2015  20
c 2015  21
g 2015  22
i 2015  23
r 2015  24
```

If you need convert `years` to `int`, use [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.astype.html):

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(df.index.str[0], df.index.str[1:].astype(int)))

print df.index
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'c', u'g', u'i', u'r', u'w'], [2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015]],
           labels=[[4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, you can:

1. reset your index

   ```
   df.reset_index(inplace=1)
   ```
2. create two other columns, one for the year, and one for the country:

   ```
   df.loc[,"year"] = df.foo.apply(lambda x: x[1:])
   df.loc[,"country"] = df.foo.apply(lambda x: x[0])
   ```

assuming that the columns of your former index is called `foo` and that the length of the country code is 1. You can adapt otherwise.

3. Set those two columns as index:

   ```
   df.set_index(["year", "country"], inplace=1)
   ```

HTH